# Making a DOS 6.22 Network Boot Floppy from a Hard Drive

Tags: networking, ms-dos, floppy

I have a computer (an oooold ALR, 486DX-66) that has a hard drive that boots to DOS 6.22.

This ALR computer boots to DOS, loads network drivers (it has an old Dlink DE-220 network card).  It then maps a drive to a Windows Server, logs in, and runs an old legacy program.  It has a floppy drive, no CD, no USB.

I am *trying* to make a DOS 6.22 boot floppy that will boot the same way the C: drive boots.  I have made a bootable floppy, I have copied the config.sys and autoexec.bat files to the floppy, along with any files that are referenced.  I also copied the c:\net3 directory files that I *thought* were necessary.  (I can't copy all of them because of a lack of floppy disk space.)  I edited the config.sys and autoexec.bat to reference the copied files on the floppy instead of the hard drive.

I can reboot the computer from the floppy drive, but it fails at the "a:\net3\net initialize" command.  This seems simple, but it's apparently not.  I have tried copying all of the *.dos, *.ini files from the c:\net3 directory, along with anything else that I could fit and that I thought was useful to the network boot.  But the "net initialize" command keeps failing.  (I'm sorry I don't have the exact error message in front of me.)

Does anyone have any instruction or knowledge about why I can't follow the same commands from a floppy that the hard drive uses?

Below are the config.sys and autoexec.bat, and the listing for the c:\net3 directory.

config.sys (I copied the himem.sys and emm386.exe to the floppy and changed to a:\himem.sys, etc...)

```
device=c:\dos\emm386.exe noems
dos=high,umb
buffers=31,0
files=71
device=C:\NET3\ifshlp.sys
LASTDRIVE=Z
```

autoexec.bat (again, this is from the c:\ drive.  I changed all the drive references to a:)

```
PROMPT $p$g
SET CLIPPER=E0 ;F75
PATH=C:\NET2;c:\;c:\dos

C:\NET3\netbind.com
C:\NET3\umb.com
C:\NET3\tcptsr.exe
C:\NET3\tinyrfc.exe
C:\NET3\nmtsr.exe
C:\NET3\emsbfr.exe

set comspec=c:\command.com
net logon clock clock /yes
net use f: \\dtsvr1\dt5
f:
cd\shoe
shoeprog
```

Here is a listing of the full C:\net3 folder:

```
 Volume in drive C is D1         
 Volume Serial Number is 4452-131E
 Directory of C:\NET3

.            <DIR>         12-05-20   2:19p
..           <DIR>         12-05-20   2:19p
WFWSYS   CFG           840 08-26-17   2:57p
SHARES   PWL           622 08-26-17   2:57p
SETUP    EXE       286,032 04-28-95  10:07a
README   TXT        18,194 05-25-95   1:55p
CONNECT  DAT            40 12-05-20   1:01a
AUTOEXEC BAT           329 12-05-20   2:36p
CLOCK    PWL           626 08-26-17   2:43p
OEMTCPIP INF         1,673 08-31-94  12:00a
PROTOCOL INI           384 12-05-20   2:25p
OEM0     INF        40,800 08-26-17   9:49a
PROTOCOL 001           123 08-26-17   1:39p
HOSTS                  754 08-26-17   3:01p
IPCONFIG EXE        11,205 08-31-94  12:00a
LMHOSTS                887 07-09-18   8:17a
NEMM     DOS         2,619 08-31-94  12:00a
NETBIND  COM         8,513 08-31-94  12:00a
NETWORKS               395 08-31-94   6:52p
NMTSR    EXE        22,826 08-31-94  12:00a
PING     EXE        66,460 08-31-94  12:00a
PROTOCOL               795 08-31-94   6:52p
SERVICES             5,973 05-08-95   2:34p
SOCKETS  EXE        50,096 09-01-94   1:22p
TCPDRV   DOS         4,174 08-31-94  12:00a
IO       SYS        40,774 05-31-94   6:22a
MSDOS    SYS        38,138 05-31-94   6:22a
TCPTSR   BAD        71,040 08-31-94  12:00a
TCPUTILS INI           233 08-31-94  12:00a
TINYRFC  EXE        37,024 12-01-94   7:39p
UMB      COM         3,325 08-31-94  12:00a
VBAPI    386         9,524 08-31-94  12:00a
VSOCKETS 386         9,535 08-31-94  12:00a
WINSOCK  DLL        48,288 01-23-95   3:21p
WIN_SOCK DLL        30,912 08-31-94  12:00a
WSOCKETS DLL        33,280 08-31-94  12:00a
WCSETUP  INF         1,477 08-31-94  12:00a
NET      MSG        76,234 03-03-95   7:11p
NETH     MSG       123,066 03-03-95   7:12p
NE2000   DOS        13,838 08-31-94  12:00a
DNR      EXE        31,312 12-16-94   6:47p
EMSBFR   EXE         4,294 08-31-94  12:00a
NET      EXE       450,326 02-07-95  12:40p
IFSHLP   SYS         4,644 08-31-94  12:00a
EXPAND   EXE        16,378 08-31-94  12:00a
RASCOPY  BAT         2,639 08-31-94  12:00a
NWLINK   EXE        27,670 08-30-94   2:05p
TCPTSR   EXE        71,040 08-31-94  12:00a
OEMRAS   INF           919 08-31-94  12:00a
OEM1     INF           478 08-26-17   9:49a
SYSTEM   INI           504 12-05-20   2:28p
OEMODI   INF           431 08-31-94  12:00a
OEMDLC   INF           688 08-31-94  12:00a
PROTOCOL 002           373 08-26-17   1:53p
PROTMAN  EXE        13,782 08-31-94  12:00a
ADDNAME  EXE        19,569 08-31-94  12:00a
SETUP    INF         1,477 08-31-94  12:00a
PROTMAN  DOS        21,940 08-31-94  12:00a
NETWORK  INF        37,231 08-31-94  12:00a
DE22X    DOS        28,832 08-26-17   9:49a
CONFIG   SYS           135 12-05-20   2:24p
       61 file(s)      1,795,710 bytes
                   2,120,613,888 bytes free
```

I have looked at netbootdisk.com, but that disk would not load the network programs into the RAM drive on the ALR.  I did not investigate why.

I would be happy to use FreeDOS, if I could boot up to the network.  But I didn't see in the documentation that as a strong point in FreeDOS.

My theory is that one of the configuration files in the \net3 folder is referencing another file that I haven't copied.

Any help, as always, is appreciated.

-T

Comment: Might be better asked on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would suggest to download a working boot diskette from [allbootdisks](https://www.allbootdisks.com/download/dos.html) and compare to find the missing piece.

Comment: And I agree with @spikey_richie .. more of us old school geeks on the site he mentions.

Comment: Thanks, @SeñorCMasMas, I will provide the exact error.  But it will take a few days because I am not onsite.  Also, all, thank you for the referral to the other site.

Comment: @harrymc, I have all the DOS files.  I've tried with and without the path statements going to the C: drive (as in the originals) to see if I'm missing something.  I've concluded that there is something that is in the c:\net3 directory that I am not including (because of space) that is causing the problem.  I also wonder what "config" files the "net initialize" command looks to.  I see that netbootdisk.com actually compresses the files to store on the floppy, then sets up a ram drive, and uncompresses them into it.  I might try that.  But that's pushing the mind pretty far back! :)

Comment: Many many years ago I had to make a bootable DOS disk for netware, and I had to compress the files and do the RAMDISK trick also.

Comment: Sorry it took so long.  After this (just for completion), I may repost as suggested.  But here are the error messages I get when I run a:\net3\net initialize:  "PRO0003E: PROTOCOL.INI file open failure / Error loading device driver PROTMAN.DOS / Error 7306: The driver failed to initialize."